# I am trying to use an array in an If statement

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to use an array in an if statement to determine whether the value of x is rare or not.

If I do it this way everything is common.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int y[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    srand(time(0));
for(int z = 0; z <= 50; z++){
    int x = 1 + (rand()%6);
    cout << z;
    cout << " " <<x;
    if(y[5] == x){
        cout << ": Common" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << ": RARE" << endl;
    }
}
```

But if I do it this way everything is rare.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int y[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    srand(time(0));
for(int z = 0; z <= 50; z++){
    int x = 1 + (rand()%6);
    cout << z;
    cout << " " <<x;
    if(y[5] == ++x){
        cout << ": Common" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << ": RARE" << endl;
    }
}
```

I am really stumped on what to do can someone please help me?

Comment: You're accessing the array out of bounds in both cases.

Comment: Indexes start at 0, so y[5] is already out of bounds of your 5-element array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are also accessing the array in position 6 (out of bounds) in both cases.  You are simply lucky that the first one works, but not the second one.

Change it to `y[4]` (array indexing starts at `0`).

Answer (score 1):

Your program has **undefined behavior**. `y[5]` is accessing the array out of bounds.

Use `y[N-1]` to access the last element of an array of size `N`, so here you should use `y[4]`